# Передача видео по RTP/RTSP. Проблема с SDP файлом

Tags: rtp, rtsp

Я пытаюсь написать небольшой *RTP/RTSP* сервер на микроконтроллерной системе (STM32F407). Использую *ffmpeg* для отображения этого потока на ПК. Проблема заключается в том, что *ffmpeg*-у не нравится мой *SDP* файл.

Выводит ошибку:

> Invalid data found when processing input.

Вот такой *SDP* файл я отдаю клиенту:

```
v=0

o=- 2525 1 IN IP4 192.168.0.56

s=stream

t=0 0

m=video 1552 RTP/AVP 97

a=rtpmap:97 H264/9000
```

Тема передачи видео по сети для меня новая. Подскажите, что я упускаю из виду?

Comment: Собрать `ffmpeg` в дебаге и посмотреть в отладчике пробовали?

Comment: Сейчас пытаюсь это сделать. Пока не очень получается. Буду благодарен за ссылку на статью по этой теме.

Comment: подключил дебагер. Из результатов работы стало ясно, что при обработке ответа на DESCRIBE ffmpeg считывает только RTSP Header. SDP файл не читает, хотя я его отправляю сразу же за Header-ом. (вижу это в снифере [пользуюсь Ethereal-ом] ).

Answer (score 0):

Нашел проблему! Она заключалась в синтаксической ошибке в слове Content-Length в хедере RTSP ответа. Отправлял поле с заголовком Content-Lenght. Через это парсер ffmpeg-а не знал какая длина моего SDP.